# Can I use a DataGrid on an ASP.Net WebForm in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, webforms

I am creating a simple WebForm using Visual Studio 2010 targeting .Net 2.0, and I can't seem to find the Datagrid in the toolbox.

Two questions:

1. Does the DataGrid exist in the Visual Studio 2010 toolbox? If so where is it (a screenshot would be awesome)
2. If not, can I add it programmatically?

Comment: it would be better to use DataGridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be there, probably under the Data section. But you could always add the markup yourself.

```
<asp:DataGrid id="yourGrid" runat="server"></asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's gridview in the toolbox. I hope you are looking for it.

Comment: please add more content to your answer